# How to detect if browser is Firefox 3.6+ or not

Tags: php, browser, user-agent

I have a PHP web page. I want to detect if browser is Firefox 3.6 or above. Can this be accomplished my just a browser-agent sniffing or is there any other way (since user agent can be customized).

Comment: or just design for all browsers like any good web developer does.

Comment: I develop cross browser sites. But this one has something to do with FF..

Comment: why -1 for my question??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using PHP, there's already an often updating `PHP Class` is there. Do have a look at it, as it features all.

Using the plugin is very simple:

```
<?php
    require_once('Browser.php');
    $browser = new Browser();
    if( ! ( $browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_FIREFOX && $browser->getVersion() >= 3 ) )
    {
        echo 'You have FireFox version 3 or greater';
    }
?>
```

For getting that `Browser.php`, please download it from: http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check the browser type and version using jQuery

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Or, using JS, you can test to see if the client has certain capabilities. jQuery has a few checks built in

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Comment: can I do it without JS? that Y not included JS tag to the question.

Comment: @blasteralfred I have a solution for you without using JavaScript, but using PHP with the help of User Agents. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way for browser detection.

Take a [look](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

```
<?php   
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

and the output will be similar to

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    /* some other infos */
)
```

Now you can redirect user into another page or show a dialog/warning message.

`[browser]` and `[version]` will help you

Comment: how can I filter browser name from `[browser_name_regex]` or `[browser_name_pattern]`? can u show me a demo? Sorry I am a beginner.. :)

Comment: @blasteralfred : told you a lie. You've alredy had what you're searchin' for. Take a look to `[browser]` and `[version]` element of the array